# Create swift closure and pass it to objective-c class as completion block

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, closures

Now I'm adding Swift code on objective-C based iOS application.

But I have a problem in calling the objective-C method from Swift side.

I'd like to get and draw image on `UIImageView` in `View` or `ViewController` which is written with Swift.
On the other hand my wrapper class of Photos Library is written with objective-C.

My wrapper class of Photos Library is below.

・MyPhotoLibraryMgr.h

```
typedef void (^AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion)(UIImage *image, NSError *error);

- (void)getImageWithTarget:(NSInteger)index
                targetSize:(CGSize)targetSize
                completion:(AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion)completion;
```

・MyPhotoLibraryMgr.m

```
- (void)getImageWithTarget:(NSInteger)index
                targetSize:(CGSize)targetSize
                completion:
(AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion)completion
{
    PHAsset *asset = _myAsetsList[index];

    PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
    options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeFast;
    options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeOpportunistic;

    [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:asset
                                               targetSize:targetSize
                                              contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                                  options:options
                                            resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                                                NSError *error = [info objectForKey:PHImageErrorKey];
                                                if (error) {
                                                    NSLog(@"error=%@", error);
                                                }
                                                completion(result, error);
                                            }];
}
```

I can get and draw image in `View` or `ViewController` written by objective-C like below,

・MyViewController.m

```
AppPhotoLibraryMgr *photoLibMgr = [AppPhotoLibraryMgr sharedInstance];
AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion completion = ^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                imageView.image = image;
};

[[AppPhotoLibraryMgr sharedInstance] getImageWithTarget:index
                                             targetSize:imageView.frame.size
                                             completion:completion];
```

But I can't get image in `View` or `ViewController` written in Swift.

・MySwiftViewController.swift

```
let completion = {(image: UIImage, error: NSError) -> AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion in
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
}

photoLibMgr?.getImageWithTarget(index, targetSize: size, completion: completion)
```

Error message from Xcode is

---

> Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage, NSError ->
>   AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion" to expected argument type
>   'AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion'

Comment: try replacing `AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion` in your swift code with `Void`

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: @NikhilManapure It didn't work by just replacing `AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion` with `Void`. I could resolve this issue with the solutions below. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declaration of `completion` variable is wrong in **MySwiftViewController.swift** file.
Edit it like this:

```
let completion: AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion = { (image, error) in
   let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
}
```

**OR**
If you don't want to declare completion handler as variable, then simply do the:

```
LinphoneLoginController.shared().getImageWithTarget(index, targetSize: size) { (image, error) in
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
}
```

Comment: I could get images with the declaration of `completion` you suggested. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The block `typedef void (^AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion)(UIImage *image, NSError *error);` in *objective-c* has return type `void`.

But the counter part in your *Swift* has return type other than `Void`. The completion block should be like:

```
let completion = {(image: UIImage, error: NSError) -> Void in
    ...
    ...
}
```

Use `typealias` for making your closure reusable.

**Example:**

```
typealias AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion = (UIImage, NSError) -> Void

let completion: AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion = { (image, error) in
    ...
    ...
}
```

**Edit: Different way**

```
photoLibMgr?.getImageWithTarget(index, targetSize: size, completion: { (image, error) in
    ...
    ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried your `typealias` but the error occurred with the message **_Cannot convert value of type '(UIImage, NSError) -> Void' to expected argument type 'AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion!'_**

Comment: Can you try the different way that I just added? Don't use typealias and don't declare `completion` property.

Comment: I could get images with your **Edit: Different way**. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, but seems you've accepted other answer. Basically the accepted answer and my answer are pretty much same.

Answer (score -1):

It should be `typedef` instead of `Typedef`. Move `typedef` on top of interface declare and don't declare it again:

```
typedef void (^AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion)(UIImage *image, NSError *error);

@interface MyPhotoLibraryMgr....
```

After the changes it should work similar in `Swift`, auto complete will change your `AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion` to `(image, error) {..}`

Comment: Thanks. It was just a mistake of coping my code. In my code don't use capital 'T' and don't declare the typedef again in interface. And the error  code is the same. I cannot work my code with the same error.

Comment: hmm...it shouldnt be any problem, try build your code again then only write the part in Swift, the suggestion may show `AppPhotoLibraryGetImageCompletion` but after press enter then it will be correct

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I cleaned once and then start "Run" on Xcode. But the result didn't change. I got the same error.