# Swift closures translation to Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this Swift function with closures:

```
static func fetchAccounts(success succeed : @escaping ((_ results:Array<Account>) -> ()),
                                   failure : @escaping ((NSError) -> ()))
```

I need to use it in an Objective C class, but I don't remember how to cast it to Objective C blocks, regarding block syntax(blocks are empty):

```
[Account fetchAccounts success:(      ){
    NSLog(@"call back success");
} failure:(     ){
    NSLog(@"call back success");
}]
```

Many thanks.

Comment: I believe you need to add `@objc` in front of your `static func fetchAccounts`

Comment: Thanks, I will do it. But which syntax I have to use in the objective C blocks?

Comment: I put an answer below

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem! Hope it solved your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you handle an Objective-C Block in this circumstance:

```
[someObject doSomethingWithBlock: ^return_type (var_type varName)
{
    //...
}];
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917428/create-swift-closure-and-pass-it-to-objective-c-class-as-completion-block) to a similar question might help.

[And this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201774/9333764) about declaring Objective-C Blocks is a great resource. It's where I got the above listed code.